# Cutting list python base on condition

Tags: python

For example:

```
my_string='ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVESIXSEVENEIGHTNINETEN'
```

and how to make it become

```
['ONE','TWO','THREE','FOUR','FIVE','SIX','SEVEN','EIGHT','NINE','TEN']
```

How can I do this efficiently without importing anything?

Comment: is the case always numbers or you don't know what comes out of my_string ?

Comment: How is *the length of each word* stored?

Comment: How is the length giveh to you?  You probably need to loop through that and parse then string.  It would be better to get something working and ask the code review stack about efficiency.  And if you can't get something working that you tried then come back here and ask a specific question *on your code*

Comment: Doesn't feel to me like you did very much research at all before asking. [See this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: "`Cutting list python base on condition`". What's the condition?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question. Do you know what the words are? Is it a list of random / arbitrary words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you know the lengths of the words this may work (you need to update the `lengths` tuple):

```
my_string='ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVESIXSEVENEIGHTNINETEN'
lengths = (3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3)

words = []
start = 0
for i in lengths:
    words.append(my_string[start:start+i])
    start += i

print(words)  # ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lengths = (3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3)

it = iter('ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVESIXSEVENEIGHTNINETEN')

words = (''.join(next(it) for _ in range(length)) for length in lengths)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match()` method for simplicity. But before that you need to have what value to match with the output from `my_string` like:

```
var my_string='ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVESIXSEVENEIGHTNINETEN';
var one = "ONE";
var array = [];

if(string.match(one)) array.push(one);
```